# Transform a nested list to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind, do.call

> I have a list of items, each of them has two items, one is a list and the other one is a character expression
>   We generate de lists

```
My_list <- list()
My_list$'product1' <- list()
My_list$'product1'$'sales' <- c(1,2,3)
My_list$'product1'$'model' <- "arima"
My_list$'product2'$'sales' <- c(4,5,6)
My_list$'product2'$'model' <- "prophet"
```

> This is the desired output shape

```
df1 <- data.frame(product=c("product1"),sales1 = 1, sales2 = 2, sales3 = 3)
df2 <- data.frame(product=c("product2"),sales1 = 4, sales2 = 5, sales3 = 6)
solution <- rbind (df1,df2)
```

> I have tried something like this

````
solution <- lapply(My_list, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, as.data.frame)))
solution <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, product = names(My_list), My_list))
```7
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple version via base R,

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(My_list), nrow = length(My_list), byrow = TRUE))
#  V1 V2 V3      V4
#1  1  2  3   arima
#2  4  5  6 prophet
```

You can easily make amendments to fit your expected output (change the names and convert `V4` to *product1* and *product2*), i.e.

```
#save the data frame
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(My_list), nrow = length(My_list), byrow = TRUE))
#Set the column names
d1 <- setNames(d1, c(paste0('sales', seq(ncol(d1) - 1)), 'Product'))
#Change the variable under `Product`
d1$Product <- paste0('Product', seq(nrow(d1)))

d1
#  sales1 sales2 sales3  Product
#1      1      2      3 Product1
#2      4      5      6 Product2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` solution. I added explanation and in-between-results in de code below as comment...

```
library(data.table)
#bind list, using name as id
DT <- rbindlist( My_list, idcol = "product" )
#     product sales   model
# 1: product1     1   arima
# 2: product1     2   arima
# 3: product1     3   arima
# 4: product2     4 prophet
# 5: product2     5 prophet
# 6: product2     6 prophet

#create rowid's by product-group, used for casting in the next line
DT[, row_id := rowid(product) ]
#     product sales   model row_id
# 1: product1     1   arima      1
# 2: product1     2   arima      2
# 3: product1     3   arima      3
# 4: product2     4 prophet      1
# 5: product2     5 prophet      2
# 6: product2     6 prophet      3

#cast to wide format
dcast( DT, product ~ paste0( "sales", row_id ), value.var = "sales" )
#     product sales1 sales2 sales3
# 1: product1      1      2      3
# 2: product2      4      5      6
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion a quite intuitive and easy to maintain method:

```
data.frame(product=names(My_list), 
           do.call(rbind, lapply(My_list, FUN=function(x) unlist(x["sales"]))), row.names = NULL)

   product sales1 sales2 sales3
1 product1      1      2      3
2 product2      4      5      6
```

It iterates through the list of lists using `lapply` and unlists all `sales` entries (which automatically names them). Then it `rbind`s the vectors together using `do.call`.

---

Quick way to add model name to the table is to use `rapply` which by default unlists the result (see `?rapply` and the argument `how`)

```
data.frame(model=rapply(My_list, f=paste, classes="character"),
           product=names(My_list), 
           do.call(rbind, lapply(My_list, FUN=function(x) unlist(x["sales"]))), row.names = NULL)

    model  product sales1 sales2 sales3
1   arima product1      1      2      3
2 prophet product2      4      5      6
```

Comment: How can I cbind "model" to the data frame?

Comment: See edit. I've included an example with `rapply`. It assumes that the only `character` class in `My_list` are the model names.

Answer (score 1):

Here a base R solution:

```
# transpose and fetch the sales arguments putting them in a df
sales <-t(do.call(cbind,
        lapply(My_list, function(x) data.frame(x[names(x)=="sales"]))))

# rename the rows with products
rownames(sales) <- names(My_list)

# rename columns 
colnames(sales) <- paste0("sales",c(1:ncol(sales)))
sales

         sales1 sales2 sales3
product1      1      2      3
product2      4      5      6
```

In case you need a data.frame with product column:

```
sales <- data.frame(sales)
sales$product <- rownames(sales)
rownames(sales) <- 1:nrow(sales)
sales
  sales1 sales2 sales3  product
1      1      2      3 product1
2      4      5      6 product2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[[` in `lapply` to get the first item *sales* from `My_list`, which you can `rbind` with `do.call`. From the result the `colnames` are set.

```
tt <- do.call(rbind, lapply(My_list, "[[", 1))
#tt <- do.call(rbind, lapply(My_list, "[[", "sales")) #Alternative
colnames(tt) <- paste0("sales",seq_len(ncol(tt)))
tt
#         sales1 sales2 sales3
#product1      1      2      3
#product2      4      5      6
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
solution <- cbind(Product = names(My_list),
                  `names<-`(r <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,sapply(My_list, `[`,-2)),row.names = FALSE),
                            paste0("Sale",seq(ncol(r)))))
```

which gives

```
> solution
   Product Sale1 Sale2 Sale3
1 product1     1     2     3
2 product2     4     5     6
```